# Convert PNG to SVG using python

Tags: svg, png, converters, wand

Is there way to convert a png file into SVG file using only pure python or a python module such as wand?

To be more precise, I want to convert a png into a real vector graphics, I don't want to embed a bitmap inside the svg, I want to convert into graphics code.

I know this is possible with Illustrator or Inkscape, but I need an automated process.

Thank you !

Comment: It seems you want an implementation of [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_tracing).

Answer (score 5):

Since the `potrace` module is not (easily) available on anaconda on Windows, I looked for an alternative. [PngToSvg](https://github.com/IngJavierR/PngToSvg) works perfectly on a python 3.6 environment in Anaconda 4.8.3 on Windows 10 Pro N.

You can clone/download the repository and run `python init.py` and that will convert the `example.png` in `/examples/` into an `example.svg` file.

Credits go to the author of the repository.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to run an external program to do the image tracing.  A popular program is potrace. It is what Inkscape uses to perform the task.

There are some python bindings for it:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypotrace

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using potrace for python.
Use this link: https://pypi.org/project/pypotrace/
Here is the documentation: https://pythonhosted.org/pypotrace/ref.html#
Like This:

```
from potrace import Bitmap

# Initialize data, for example convert a PIL image to a numpy array
# [...]

bitmap = Bitmap(data)
path = bitmap.trace()
```

Comment: how to convert `path` to svg? which has areas to be filled with colours

Answer (score 1):

I'm using https://github.com/ianmackinnon/png2svg to convert low resolution QR-Codes to SVG to print them in arbitrary sizes.
It works pretty well, the codes look as expected and are scalable to arbitrary sizes.

However, 2 small (but negligible, at least for me) caveats:
- Conversion takes about a minute or so on my machine for a low resolution image (400x400)
- The file sizes are larger than they should be, compared to an optimized SVG

Comment: This answer referrers a repo which doesn't exists anymore

Comment: No, it doesn't. The link is working fine (for me, anyway).