# how to convert jpg or png image to svg and save it?

Tags: python, svg

I have png image that I used opencv cv2 to load as follow:

```
im1 = cv2.imread("/media/mark/B37B-0280/dataset_grad/test/formatted/200000.png", 0)
```

what I want is to convert it to svg so I tried the potrace as suggested in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427903/convert-png-to-svg-using-python) but when I do the following:

```
bmp = potrace.Bitmap(im1)
path = bmp.trace()
```

it does not save the image.. I do not know how to save it as svg after those steps.. please kindly help me

Answer (score 2):

Potrace will do.  Just copy from [converting-png-to-svg](https://eprev.org/2015/05/27/converting-png-to-svg/)

On my MAC, install `imagemagic` and `potrace` with the following commands.

```
brew install pottrace
brew install imagemagic
```

And use the following to convert:

```
convert -alpha remove party-never.png pgm: \
| mkbitmap -f 32 -t 0.4 - -o - \
| potrace --svg -o party-never.svg
```

It converts PNG file to PGM format, removes image transparency, outputs the result image to the standard input of mkbitmap that transforms the input with highpass filtering and thresholding into a suitable for the potrace program format, that finally generates SVG file. You can play around with highpass filtering (-f) and thresholding (-t) values until you have the final look that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, the  `pypotrace` lib doesn't have any support for saving SVGs.  It just lets you get the vector commands that comprise the outline of whatever image you pass in.

Instead, use the `potrace` binary directly.  Something like:

```
os.system("potrace my.png --svg -o my.svg")
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't have so much experient in Python but i have a solution for you:

```
import os
startSvgTag = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
width="240px" height="240px" viewBox="0 0 240 240">"""endSvgTag = """</svg>"""
for files in os.listdir("."):
if files.endswith(".png"):
pngFile = open(files, 'rb')
base64data = pngFile.read().encode("base64").replace('\n','')
base64String = '<image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,{0}" width="240" 
height="240" x="0" y="0" />'.format(base64data)
f = open(os.path.splitext(files)[0]+".svg",'w')
f.write( startSvgTag + base64String + endSvgTag)
print 'Converted '+ files + ' to ' + os.path.splitext(files)[0]+".svg"
```

This is code from [enter link description here](http://sachinpatil.com/blog/2013/03/26/python-tips/).If it don't true you can comment below