# How to convert .PNG to .SVG in python or shell on Mac Big Sur (tried Inkscape Shell)?

Tags: python, terminal, inkscape

I have a folder with a bunch of .PNG files that I would like to convert to .SVGs.  I downloaded Inkscape and was able to manually convert a few of them, but soon I will need to convert a lot of .PNGs to .SVGs and it will not be feasible to do it manually.

I looked into Inkscape's shell feature and activated it as follows on the terminal on Mac Big Sur:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape --shell
```

but then when I use this code:

```
--export-plain-svg /Users/Downloads/pictures/testpic.png
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to find: --export-plain-svg /Users/Downloads/pictures/testpic.png
verbs_action: Invalid verb: --export-plain-svg /Users/Downloads/pictures/testpic.png
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert PNG to SVG using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427903/convert-png-to-svg-using-python)

Comment: I've heard popytrace is only black and white, but would need color functionality, which I have heard inkscape shell has, but there seems to be minimal documentation

Comment: @Meowsleydale: Do you mean how to batch convert PNGs to SVG using Trace bitmap?

Comment: Well, what I want to do is take a bunch of .PNG files and somehow batch convert them to .SVG files, retaining full color, but theres not much documentation out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try https://www.visioncortex.org/vtracer (https://github.com/visioncortex/vtracer)
Opensource tool to convert color pngs to svg, Inkscape is not ok with colors AFAIK

Comment: Whoa this looks really great.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

(Not a solution, but a clarification)

Inkscape's command-line option `--export-plain-svg` simply removes some XML metadata from an existing .svg file. The option `--export-plain-svg`does *not* do this: "import the PNG, automagically converts/"vectorize" it, then export it as SVG."

The feature that you need is called "Trace Bitmap" (Menu Path / Trace Bitmap, or SHIFT+ALT+B) [(example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721556/vectorizing-a-raster-drawing). Also the "Fill Bounded Areas" AKA Paint-Bucket Tool (U) can be used for tracing shapes within simple PNGs. Both of these require some manual experimentation first.

---

Specifically `--export-plain-svg` removes XML attributes that are in these namespaces:

```
xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
```

("sodipodi" is a veryold precursor-project name, before the renaming to "Inkscape" happened, AFAIK)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this response, in that other thread, what would he have had to have used in order to get it traced and colored, and saved as a svg?  Really appreciate your help with this, as it seems documentation is sparse, and your post is helping to clarify it.