# Creating vector graphics from images and save in svg, to later visualize in illustrator

Tags: python, vector-graphics

I will have images like the following in terms of color and complexity. These will be created with hand drawing and then scanned.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc8gm.png)

Then maybe after some series of filters there will be black complex shapes on white bg in a bitmap.

Now, I would like to find contours of these and then create an svg vector graphic to work in Adobe Illustrator.

Of course, hard way of saying that is:

I would like to find contours of these black shapes,
fit splines, lines, and vertices,
create a vector graphic,
save it in svg...

How is that possible?

Is there a library for this that I should dive deep,
or I should construct my own algorithm in order to achieve the result?

Comment: So you did not find this question with answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427903/convert-png-to-svg-using-python

Comment: I found that "Potrace" library does that for you. And I would like to see the possibilities to use this in python. Because, then I will create a gui to do this and several more things  to create different variants of a vector composition .